# .htaccess files directive not working to block all IPs but allow mine

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several wordpress sites installed in their respective directories under `public_html/` and I want to restrict access to `public_html/dev/wp-login.php`. The `dev` folder is the root of the WordPress installation for that site.

Since I have Apache 2.4.12 I updated the blocking directive to the new syntax... here's `public_html/dev/.htaccess` now

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    Require all denied
    # Whitelist my IP
    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This setup will **block access to all IPs,** not allowing mine. Removing it leaves `wp-login.php` accessible to all.

Is there something wrong within this code itself? Is something else interfering with it?

The moment it sees `Require all denied` (or `Deny from all`) everything stops.
I've checked, double- and triple-checked my IP.

Comment: I don't mean to sound flippant, but this does suggest you are allowing the wrong IP address? What version of Apache is this (your directives imply Apache 2.2)? Do you have another WP site in the document root? Do the WP sites in subdirectories enable mod_rewrite inheritance? If not, then the blocking directives in the parent `.htaccess` file will not be processed, but if it is then you have a front controller in the parent `.htaccess` that will break the site - so I guess not?

Comment: @user82217 It's definitely the right IP address, I checked. I have renamed `/public_html/.htaccess` temporarily to disable any inherited rules, but the problem persisted. Maybe it's an issue within `/public_html/dev/.htaccess` itself, where I put in the directive? I tried temporarily commenting out different sections of its code one by one, but the problem remained.